# Java web app - cache data between asynchronous requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, asynchronous, web-applications

In my application I have multiple Asynchronous http requests to the server Per user click.
Each request going to service layer and accessing DAO layer for data.
Some of the requests are using the same data from database.

So, it ends up doing same work from DB many times.
I would like to improve performance.

From architecture design perspective,
What would you suggest me to do ?
Should I use cache, if so when should I clean it ?

I'm using Spring MVC and all the bean are singletons.
both services and DAO layer.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash table to store your data there.
before you query your DB, check if you already have the data in your hash table.

I don't know when you should clean the data because I don't know what kind of data you will store there.
but you can clean data by LRU or expiration time.